# Laravel get rows from table using timestamp column

Tags: php, laravel

In my table, I have 2 columns:
1-`count_of_h` 2- `updated_at`

Now I want select rows which is past the `updated_at`, `count_of_h` hours.

A code like this:
`$rows = Model::where('updated_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subHours($row->count_of_h))->get();`
But I don't know how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

My code is kinda dirty ( but it works )

```
$arrayOfData = [];
Model::chunk(100, function($model) {
    foreach($model as $m) {
         if($m->updated_at < Carbon::now()->subHours($m->count_of_h)) {
               $arrayOfData[] = $m;
         }
    }
});
```

First is make an array. After that, it will take every 100 rows then check if its past count_of_h hours